# Eclipse Keppler java 1.7 error in jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I work with Eclipse Keppler and Java 1.7.

I have the following jsp

```
<c:choose> 
<c:when test='${attributeName.name.equals("Owner")}'> 
/*    <c:when test="${attributeName.name == 'Owner'}">  */
$(td).append(list[i].owner);
</c:when>
<c:otherwise> 
$(td).append(getAttributeValue(list[i].attributes, '${attributeName.id}', '${attributeName.name}'));
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

In the Keppler editor I have the following error

[image]

I configured the values:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is it something wrong in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import JSTL jar and add

```
`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` at top of jsp page
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an Eclipse bug. It looks similar to [the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394147).

You may have to use new version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug , anyway doing like below will prevent even different kind of errors in jsp

**Project properties --> Validation --> disable all validators in the grid**